# Form option required AND not required

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a big problem and after hours of research I haven't find any answer...

I have **2 forms**, and i'm calling one in the other.
When i give to my form the "entity_manager" option I have this error message :

> The option "entity_manager" does not exist.

*BUT*, when i delete this option I have the following :

> The required option "entity_manager" is missing.

There is my code :

**CandidatureController.php**

```
$candidature = new Candidature();
$formCandidature = $this->createForm('PDF\RecrutementBundle\Form\CandidatureType', $candidature, array('entity_manager' => $entityManager, 'form' => 'candidature'));
$formCandidature->handleRequest($request);
$formOrientation = $this->createForm('PDF\RecrutementBundle\Form\CandidatureType', $candidature, array('entity_manager' => $entityManager, 'form' => 'orientation'));
```

**CandidatureType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $this->em = $options['entity_manager'];
    $form = $options['form'];

    if ($form == 'candidature') {
        $builder->add('caCommentairesituation', TextareaType::class)
                ->add('caCommentaire', TextareaType::class)
                ->add('profils', CollectionType::class, array('entry_options' => ['entity_manager' => $this->em], 'entry_type' => ProfilType::class,'allow_add' => true, 'allow_delete' => true,'prototype' => true))
                ->add('fkMobilitegeographique', EntityType::class, array('class'=>'PDF\RecrutementBundle\Entity\Mobilitegeographique', 'choice_label'=>'mgLibelle'))
                ->add('fkSituationprofessionnelle',EntityType::class, array('class'=>'PDF\RecrutementBundle\Entity\Situationprofessionnelle', 'choice_label'=>'spLibelle'))
                ->add('fkTypecandidature', EntityType::class, array('class'=>'PDF\RecrutementBundle\Entity\Typecandidature', 'choice_label'=>'tcLibelle'))
                ->add('fkProvenance', EntityType::class, array('class'=>'PDF\RecrutementBundle\Entity\Provenance', 'choice_label'=>'prLibelle'));
    } else {
        $builder->add('orientations', CollectionType::class, array('entry_options' => ['entity_manager' => $this->em], 'entry_type' => OrientationType::class, 'allow_add' => true, 'allow_delete' => true, 'prototype' => true));
    }
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'PDF\RecrutementBundle\Entity\Candidature',
        'form' => false
    ));
    $resolver->setRequired('entity_manager');
}
```

**OrientationType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('orLibelle', TextType::class)
            ->add('orDescription', TextType::class)
            ->add('orArchive')
            ->add('orDiffusion')
            ->add('fkCategorieorientation', EntityType::class, array('class'=>'PDF\RecrutementBundle\Entity\CategorieOrientation', 'choice_label'=>'coLibelle'))
            ->add('candidatures', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => CandidatureType::class, 'allow_add' => true, 'allow_delete' => true));
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'PDF\RecrutementBundle\Entity\Orientation'
    ));
}
```

So how can I resolve this ?

*PS* : Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OrientationType.php, the entry type for your CollectionType "candidatures" is CandidatureType but you don't define 'entry_options' wich are options you pass to your entry type...

try to replace that

```
 ->add('candidatures', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => CandidatureType::class, 'allow_add' => true, 'allow_delete' => true))
```

with that :

```
  ->add('candidatures', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type' => CandidatureType::class, 
    'entry_options' => [
       'entity_manager' => $this->em
    ],
    'allow_add' => true, 
    'allow_delete' => true)
);
```

Of course, you need to define $em as the entity_manager first in OrientationType, the same way you defined it in CandidatureType, with setRequired() should be just fine.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now I have an error 500 but its an other problem.
Thanks again.